# Query to Join Lab Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to write a query for a laboratory I work with in SQL Server.  They are interested in a report that has results from two specific tests, Test1 and Test2.  I have created two tables, with each table having three columns:

```
AccessionNumber, TestName, TestResult
```

In table #1, there could be data that looks like

```
123456, Test1, TestResult
```

In table #2, there could be data that looks like

```
123456, Test2, TestResult
```

But there may be combinations of the two depending whether or not both tests were run or just one was run.  I.E. there could be a Test1, but not a Test2, and vice versa.

How can I join these two tables together?  Matching on the AccessionNumber (which is unique).  Ideally the output would be:

```
AccessionNumber, Test1, Result1, Test2, Result2
```

Nulls are fine if there is not a matching test and result in the opposite table.

I have tried everything from joins to crossjoins to unions, and can't seem to get past the hump.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method is a full join:

```
select coalesce(t1.AccessionNumber, t2.AccessionNumber) as AccessionNumber,
       t1.TestName, t1.TestResult,
       t2.TestName, t2.TestResult,
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.AccessionNumber = t2.AccessionNumber;
```

Note:  This assumes that `AccessionNumber` is unique in each table -- which seems quite reasonable based on the question.  If it can be duplicated, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question along with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: I actually just lost connection to my remote system when I was testing and will report back once it's back up and running, but to clarify, yes the `AccessionNumber` is unique in each table, only one row per Accession Number, however, that number can be present in both tables.

Comment: @Bke . . . Then this should do what you want.